# FMDB, Swift 3, executeUpdate - compiler build failed

Tags: compilation, swift3, fmdb

I'm using FMDB with Swift 3.
Everything worked fine on Swift 2 but after making the Swift upgrade I'm getting:
"Command failed due to signal: Killed: 9"

After investigating the cause of it I've found that doing "executeUpdate" with about 24 arguments in the ArgumentsArray cause the compiler to be very slow and finally return compilation error.

When decreasing the number of arguments in the array to 20, the compiler build is still slow but succeed to finish successfully.

Any idea why/help will be welcome... !

Here is my code:
(Build succeed but uncommenting the 4 lines below will make the compilation build failed. Any other 4 lines will have same result of course)

```
func insertLocalization(_ localization: Localization) -> Bool {
        print ("Insert Localization: \(localization.localization_object_id!)#\(localization.spot_object_id!)#\(localization.language_code!)")
        sharedInstance.database!.open()
        let isInserted = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate(
            "INSERT INTO localizations (" +
                "localization_object_id, " +
                "spot_object_id, " +
                "language_code, " +
                "current_location_enabled, " +
                "spot_title, " +
                "spot_desc, " +
                "local_assistant_phone, " +
                "orientation_360_enabled, " +
                "direction_n_title, " +
                "direction_n_desc, " +
                "direction_ne_title, " +
                "direction_ne_desc, " +
                "direction_e_title, " +
                "direction_e_desc," +
                "direction_se_title, " +
                "direction_se_desc, " +
                "direction_s_title, " +
                "direction_s_desc, " +
                "direction_sw_title, " +
                "direction_sw_desc, " +
                "direction_w_title, " +
                "direction_w_desc, " +
                "direction_nw_title, " +
                "direction_nw_desc) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            withArgumentsIn: [
                // localization.localization_object_id!,
                // localization.spot_object_id!,
                // localization.language_code!,
                // localization.current_location_enabled!,
                localization.spot_title!,
                localization.spot_desc!,
                localization.local_assistant_phone!,
                localization.orientation_360_enabled!,
                localization.direction_n_title!,
                localization.direction_n_desc!,
                localization.direction_ne_title!,
                localization.direction_ne_desc!,
                localization.direction_e_title!,
                localization.direction_e_desc!,
                localization.direction_se_title!,
                localization.direction_se_desc!,
                localization.direction_s_title!,
                localization.direction_s_desc!,
                localization.direction_sw_title!,
                localization.direction_sw_desc!,
                localization.direction_w_title!,
                localization.direction_w_desc!,
                localization.direction_nw_title!,
                localization.direction_nw_desc!
            ])
        sharedInstance.database!.close()
        return isInserted
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles without incident for me in Xcode 8.0 (8A218a). But if this isn't working for you, I'd suggest splitting the line up, for example

```
let values =  [localization.localization_object_id!, ..., localization.direction_nw_desc!]

let isInserted = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate(
    "INSERT INTO localizations (...) " +
    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    withArgumentsIn: values)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help :(
My current temporary solution was to divide it into 2 operations 
first: INSERT the

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help :( My current temporary solution was to divide the INSERT operation into 2 operations: first, INSERT the first 8 columns, afterwards, UPDATE the inserted record with last 16 columns. Practical though but not so elegant solution for my opinion.